# Copy files from VCD without conversion to MPEG

Tags: linux, fedora, linux-kernel

I'm using a Fedora 23-like OS (Korora) and recently I got my hands on an old VCD. Korora recognized it as a "Video CD" all right and Nautilus even gave me an option to play using VLC. But as soon as I clicked the button VLC threw several IO errors as follows:

```
File reading failed:
VLC could not read the file (Input/output error).
Unidentified codec:
VLC could not identify the audio or video codec
File reading failed:
VLC could not read the file (Input/output error).
File reading failed:
VLC could not read the file (Input/output error).
Unidentified codec:
VLC could not identify the audio or video codec
```

Then I tried copying the entire CD using "Create a Partition Image" feature of Disks application. Unfortunately, Disks complained that:

```
 99.7% (401.3 MB) of the data on the device “CD/DVD Drive — TSSTcorp CDDVDW
 SU-228HB [AS00] (/dev/sr0)” was unreadable and replaced with zeroes in the
 created disk image file. This typically happens if the medium is scratched
 or if there is physical damage to the drive.
```

Upon researching this issue I came across a similar issue in a related cross site question [Playing VCDs on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42660/playing-vcds-on-ubuntu?rq=1). This worked for the part that I'm now able to play all sorts of VCDs to my hearts content, but this raises a few questions in my mind.

1. **How on earth is VLC able to play the contents of VCD** when even the kernel, apparently, cannot read all sectors properly and is just able to show the directory structure?
2. **How can I copy such kind of discs?** I've tried this on Windows and it works very well. Windows can read all the files it shows in the directory structure. Linux, in general, is only able to show the directory structure.

Question 2 is important for me. Most related questions have solutions that just discuss how to play VCD using VLC or MPlayer without giving any info on a way to actually copy the entire partition.

Please do not answer this question if your solution is to use `vcdxrip` or to use *VLC's conversion* feature. They're ridiculously slow as compared to simple copying that I found on Windows.

Comment: Please read the entire question. Windows is able to read it all right and this happens with all VCDs. I wrote the V in VCD as I encounter trouble with only these kind of CDs.

Comment: Did that warning about the disk error which is possibly a scratch abort the process and delete the file.  That's not the impression the message gives me which looks OK.  It could either be a scratch as mentioned or an intentional defect to do some kind of copy protection.

Comment: As I said in the question, answers in http://askubuntu.com/questions/42660/playing-vcds-on-ubuntu?rq=1 , work with all VCDs, but that's not exactly my question. Simple copying fails on all VCDs in Linux (I've tried this in Ubuntu as well) and works flawlessly in Windows.

Comment: Does it keep the copied file after the warning or not?  And if you want to do some comparison, what tool do you use on Windows to copy the disk?

Comment: Mostly the entire ISO file is filled with 0s if I attempt to keep it, so I delete it anyways. VLC, however, is able to play it if I go according to the link above. I don't need any tool in Windows to copy. File Explorer is sufficient.

Comment: [This](http://littlesvr.ca/linux-stuff/articles/how-to-copy-vcd/how-to-copy-vcd.php) googled *howto* uses *vcdxrip*, which is part of [vcdimager](https://www.gnu.org/software/vcdimager/). Apparently what the filesystem sees is not the real VCD structure (just like e.g. an audio CD), so neither copying these, nor instructing VLC to play such a file will work.

Comment: Try cdrdao as mentioned [here](http://palashray.com/how-to-rip-vcd-on-linux/). Looks like this gets around the kernel nut understanding the files system of VCDs.

Comment: Is your question 2 possible related to a permissions issue?  In other words your Window's user has the permission necessary to read everything but the Linux user can only see directory listings?

Comment: Looking at the Ubuntu link you gave, it appears that the command line version includes a _protocol_, `vcd://`. That might be a angle of attack to follow. Maybe mount the disc using a protocol, as you do for NAS?

Comment: It might not be very helpfull but in Debian i copied (not rip) yesterday one dvd with vobcopy.... and it worked perfectly.

Comment: A brief description of the construction of the VCD can be found http://www7.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/vcd.html.
It follows that you should use a program that supports "XA mode 2".
For example, a program http://sudoku9x9.cba.pl/vcdplayk/vcd2mpg.tar.gz.

Answer (score 3):

I'm on Debian with KDE.

After searching and testing I found a solution and then found this thread. @agc's response is valuable, but @dirkt's comment is a direct response to your question and it would have saved me a lot of time had I found it earlier.

You've asked how to *copy files from VCD without conversion to MPEG*. Video files on a VCD disk are an MPEG stream already. Some responses I found said it is sufficient to copy the .dat file and rename it to .mpg. Examining the file's content seems to support it, but I wasn't able to simply copy the .dat file to my hard drive to verify it. What worked for me was `vcdxrip`, included in `vcdimager` package. You've explicitly asked to exclude these from responses, but on my system it was the only tool which, slowly but surely, copied files (as opposed to creating an ISO image).

1. Install it with `apt-get install vcdimager`
2. Insert the VCD into the drive. It does not need to be mounted.
3. Open the terminal and navigate to the directory on your hard drive where you want the files from the VCD.
4. Run `vcdxrip -vpC`

Files from the VCD will be copied to the current directory. In the above command:

- `v` is for verbosity
- `p` is to show progress
- `C` designates the CD-ROM drive as source

I hope this response helps others looking for a solution, even though it may not be as fast as you were able to get on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This method works with certain copy protected/scratched DVDs.  Having no VCDs around, I'm not sure this works with the puzzle of copying VCDs, (i.e. a disc that *plays*, so it should copy, yet doesn't), but it might be worth a shot.

The jist of the method is that when `mplayer` or `vlc` is running, it's possible to copy discs that otherwise won't copy when they're *not* running.  Better yet, the copy goes quickly, and doesn't tend to hang on bad blocks.

So the *vcd* version, should go something like:

1. Open a terminal, and let `mplayer` play the *vcd* -- since there's no need to see or hear it, *null* output is sufficient:

   ```
   mplayer  -really-quiet -slave -vo null -ao null \
            vcd://1 -cdrom-device /dev/cdrom
   ```

   Wait 5 seconds, then press `p` for *pause*.
   Now just let it alone and leave it paused.
2. Open *another* terminal, (leaving the other terminal to play in the background), and use `ddrescue` to copy the disc image:

   ```
   ddrescue -r 0 -b 2Ki /dev/cdrom foobar.iso foobar.log
   ```
3. When `ddrescue` finishes, return to the terminal with `mplayer` running, and type `q` to *quit*.

---

For the record, here's the *dvd* version, which does work...

1. Open a terminal, and let `mplayer` play the *dvd* -- since there's no need to see or hear it, *null* output is sufficient:

   ```
   mplayer  -really-quiet -slave -vo null -ao null \
            dvdnav://1 -dvd-device /dev/dvd
   ```

   Wait 5 seconds, then press `p` for *pause*.
   Now just let it alone and leave it paused.
2. Open *another* terminal, leaving the other one to play in the background, and use `ddrescue` to copy the disc image:

   ```
   ddrescue -r 0 -b 2Ki /dev/dvd foobar.iso foobar.log
   ```
3. When `ddrescue` finishes, return to the terminal with `mplayer` running, and type `q` to *quit*.

Comment: That, if it works, will copy the disk image to be mounted latter, but doesn't answer the OPs Q. He wants to copy the **files** from the VCD.